# Date Calculation based on reference column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Its little critical.... may anyone share your expertise.

DDL:-

```
CREATE TABLE mytable

(
SUPERID     INT,
DATE_RECORDED DATETIME2,
SUPPLIER_SKU VARCHAR (50),
PRICEINCVAT DECIMAL (14,4),
[DESC] VARCHAR (100),
FROM_DATE DATETIME2,
ACTIVE BIT

)

INSERT mytable

SELECT 1000001,   '2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000',      '0 986 490 640',  '29.5400',      'CAPACITOR',      '2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001,   '2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000',      '2347402',  '32.6900',  'CAPACITOR',      '2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000',      0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001,   '2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000',      'FDB779',   '30.9200',  'CAPACITOR',      '2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001,   '2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000',      'GDB1577',  '29.3600',  'CAPACITOR',      '2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000',0UNION ALL

SELECT 1000001,   '2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000',      '0 986 490 640',      '29.5400','CAPACITOR','2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000'   ,1UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001,   '2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000',      '2347402',  '32.6900',  'CAPACITOR',      '2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000',1UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001,   '2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000',      'FDB779',   '30.1800',  'CAPACITOR',      '2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000',1UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001,   '2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000',      'GDB1577','29.3600',    'CAPACITOR',      '2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000',1 UNION ALL


SELECT 1000017,   '2015-12-18 06:47:00.0000000',      'GDB1496',  '29.5400',  'CAPACITOR',      '2015-12-18 06:47:00.0000000',      0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000017,   '2016-03-03 02:24:00.0000000',      'GDB1496',  '29.5400',  'CAPACITOR',      '2016-03-03 02:24:00.0000000',      1  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,   '3/8/2016  11:04:00 PM',      'FDB1751',  '29.5400',  'CAPACITOR',      '3/2/2016  11:04:00 PM',      1  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,   '12/12/2015  7:12:00 AM',     'FDB1751',  '29.5400',  'CAPACITOR',      '12/18/2015  7:12:00 AM',     0  UNION ALL

SELECT 1000653,  '2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000','0 986 494 096','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR', '2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000', '0 986 494 096','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR', '2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000', '16531','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR', '2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000','2393501','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR','2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000',0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000', '2393501','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR','2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000','FDB1751','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR','2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000','FDB1751','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR','2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000','GDB1625','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR', '2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000','GDB1625','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR','2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000653,  '2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000','LP1925','29.5400', 'CAPACITOR', '2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000',1
```

i am trying to calculate value for TO_DATE which will be 1 sec less than highest date available in a FROM_DATE in group of SUPERID order by FROM_DATE. where ACTIVE COLUMN value would be 0. but where ACTIVE column = 1 , then it would be default (9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000)

Expected Output:

```
SUPERID DATE_RECORDED   SUPPLIER_SKU    PRICEINCVAT DESC    FROM_DATE   TO_DATE ACTIVE

1000001 2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000 0 986 490 640   29.5400 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000 2016-03-03 02:21:59.0000000 0
1000001 2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000 2347402 32.6900 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000 2016-03-03 02:21:59.0000000 0
1000001 2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000 FDB779  30.9200 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000 2016-03-03 02:21:59.0000000 0
1000001 2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000 GDB1577 29.3600 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 06:45:00.0000000 2016-03-03 02:21:59.0000000 0
1000001 2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000 0 986 490 640   29.5400 CAPACITOR   2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000001 2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000 2347402 32.6900 CAPACITOR   2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000001 2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000 FDB779  30.1800 CAPACITOR   2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000001 2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000 GDB1577 29.3600 CAPACITOR   2016-03-03 02:22:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000017 2015-12-18 06:47:00.0000000 GDB1496 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 06:47:00.0000000 2016-03-03 02:23:59.0000000 0
1000017 2016-03-03 02:24:00.0000000 GDB1496 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2016-03-03 02:24:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000653 2015-12-12 07:12:00.0000000 FDB1751 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 0
1000653 2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 0 986 494 096   29.5400 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 0
1000653 2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 2393501 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 0
1000653 2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 FDB1751 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 0
1000653 2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 GDB1625 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 0
1000653 2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 LP1925  29.5400 CAPACITOR   2015-12-18 07:12:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000653 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 GDB1625 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000653 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 FDB1751 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000653 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 2393501 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000653 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 0 986 494 096   29.5400 CAPACITOR   2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000653 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 16531   29.5400 CAPACITOR   2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000653 2016-03-08 23:04:00.0000000 FDB1751 29.5400 CAPACITOR   2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
```

Code i tried but not giving correct result:

```
;WITH cte AS (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUPERID ORDER BY FROM_DATE) as RN
      FROM mytable m
)
SELECT c.SUPERID, c.DATE_RECORDED, c.SUPPLIER_SKU, c.PRICEINCVAT, c.[DESC], c.FROM_DATE,   
      CASE
            WHEN c.ACTIVE = 0 THEN DATEADD(second, -1, c2.FROM_DATE)
            ELSE '9999-12-31'
      END as TO_DATE,
      c.ACTIVE
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c.SUPERID = c2.SUPERID
                        AND c.RN = c2.RN - 1
```

May someone please share if it is possible in SQL.
Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the result you get from your current query?

Comment: @TabAlleman: for example superid 1000653 has max from date is 2016-03-02 23:04:00.0000000, then all TO_DATE will be 2016-03-02 23:03:59.0000000 where active = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use OUTER APPLY to get the MAX(FROM_DATE) - 1 second.

```
SELECT  SUPERID,
        DATE_RECORDED,
        SUPPLIER_SKU,
        PRICEINCVAT,
        [DESC],
        FROM_DATE,
        CASE WHEN ACTIVE = 1 THEN '9999-12-31' ELSE TO_DATE END AS TO_DATE,
        ACTIVE
FROM    mytable mt
        OUTER APPLY (   SELECT  MAX(DATEADD(second, -1, FROM_DATE)) TO_DATE 
                        FROM    mytable mt2 
                        WHERE   mt2.SUPERID = mt.SUPERID 
                                AND mt2.SUPPLIER_SKU = mt.SUPPLIER_SKU 
                                AND mt2.From_DATE > mt.From_DATE  ) oa
```

Comment: Sorry Jamie.... this is not giving correct result. where 1 is in Active column Than TO_DATE has to be default value as 9999-12-31. but when i test the logic, it is also giving other than default value in TO_DATE COLUMN for Active = 1. please help

Comment: I added SUPPLIER_SKU to the WHERE clause.. that might fix it for you

Comment: Sorry: even than it not got fixed. may i edit question with the example.

Comment: if the only issue is that not all Active = 1 records have default value that is an easy fix.. but need to be sure that is the only issue

Comment: i updated the answer already to force ACTIVE=1 to always be '9999-12-31'.. it's the CASE WHEN ACTIVE = 1 part

Comment: Thanks a lot JamieD77.. i will mark it as answer in couple of min

Answer (score 0):

I find the question difficult to follow.  But, I'm expecting a construct like this:

```
select m.*,
       dateadd(second, -1,
               max(from_date) over (partition by superid)
              ) as new_to_date
from mytable m;
```

I don't see how `row_number()` fits into the logic.

Comment: WHEN ACTIVE = 0, then only it should calculate the -1 sec from max datetime of from_date, in a group of Superid. WHEN ACTIVE = 1 then it should be default 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000